# QT many layers of window

Tags: c++, qt

Recently I've been working on my project in QT creator. I wanted to build it only on one window but I find it difficult. I've not found something like layers, that I can apply to the window.

What i mean is that I'd like to hide actual content of my window and replace it with other. How could I make many layers in Designer mode?

Comment: just design it first and then then make a function that hides/show content1, content2 , content3 ... expect that the designer is going to be a mess lol because you are gonna put content on top of other content (on a single window)and so on..

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html):

> The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time.

But don’t overdo it. After a certain point complexity tends to kill you quickly in Qt Designer. One simple solution is to design each of the “layers” in their own QWidget-derived class and just combine them on the final QStackedWidget. That last step is probably simple enough that you don’t even need Designer for it.